# create array and object using push and forEach

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's wrong with my code below? `grandParent` is undefined, what I want to achieve is each grandparent have a property of parent, and each parent have child (arrays of object too)

like so

```
[{
  name: 'a',
  parent: [{
    name: 'b',
    child: [{
      name: 'c'
    }]
  }]
}]
```

below code doesn't work

```
let grandParent = []

_.times(5, () => grandParent.push({
  name: faker.name.findName(),
  parent: []
}))

grandParent = grandParent.forEach(function(o) {
  return o.parent.push({ name: faker.name.findName() })
})

console.log(grandParent) //why here is undefined?
```

Comment: Click `<>` and create a [mcve] - include lowdash or whatever framework you use

Comment: it is `undefined` because `Array.prototype.forEach` returns `undefined`. You don't need to reassign `grandParent`. Also you don't need to return from `forEach` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MDN docs of [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> Return value: undefined

```js
let grandParent = [
{ name: 'grandname0',  parent: [] },
{ name: 'grandname1',  parent: [] },
{ name: 'grandname2',  parent: [] },
{ name: 'grandname3',  parent: [] },
{ name: 'grandname4',  parent: [] }
];


grandParent.forEach(function(o) {
  
  o.parent.push({ name: 'parent1' });
  
});
console.log(grandParent);
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` doesn't return anything, you must use `map` instead. Also `push` returns the new size of the array, to return a new array use `concat`

```
grandParent = grandParent.map(function(o) {
  return o.parent.concat([{ name: faker.name.findName() }])
})

console.log(grandParent)
```

Other way to do it is to not return anything from forEach and just update the original array.

```
grandParent = grandParent.forEach(function(o) {
    o.parent.push({ name: faker.name.findName()})
})

console.log(grandParent)
```

Comment: the second example won't work. I think you need to remove `grandParent =`

Comment: Sorry for the error there, it should have been push instead of concat in the second example. It was a copy paste error

Comment: your first example have problem too, look at this https://jsbin.com/xoqecuvaha/edit?html,js,console. The result that I expect is like wscourge's answer.

Answer (score 0):

[.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does not return anything. using the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function will help. You code should look something like this.

```
let grandParent = []

_.times(5, () => grandParent.push({
  name: faker.name.findName(),
  parent: []
}))

grandParent = grandParent.map(function(o) {
  return o.parent.concat({ name: faker.name.findName() })
})
```

console.log(grandParent)